# Java nested generics: what should be the formal parameter type?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I've come across a situation where it is not clear how to make the code compile, although it can be easily solved by making a new method in each subclass instead of one method in the superclass (but that looks ugly!) I've simplified my code, so that I start with a chain of classes (I declare them static just for convenience):

```
interface U0 { }
static class U1 implements U0 {
    public int x = 1;
}
static class U2 extends U1 { }
```

Then, there is an abstract class that does something with some container:

```
static abstract class M<U extends U0, C extends List<? extends U>> {
    C field;
    public abstract boolean check(C c);
}
```

and an example of a derived class acting on U1 or any descendant of U1 (say, U2):

```
static class M1 extends M<U1, List<? extends U1>> {

    @Override
    public boolean check(List<? extends U1> c) {
        return !c.isEmpty() && c.get(0).x > 0;
    }

}
```

Now, let's say I wish to extend the container, first adding a generic class:

```
static class MyList<U extends U0> extends ArrayList<U> {
    ...
}
```

and a derived class that calls "check" method of M:

```
static class MyList1 extends MyList<U2> {
    void test() {
        M1 m1 = new M1();
        m1.check(this);
    }
}
```

All this works so far, but now I wish to replace the lines

```
M1 m1 = new M1();
m1.check(this);
```

with a single call

```
callCheck(new M1());
```

to some method declared in MyList. Thus, the class MyList now changes to

```
static class MyList<U extends U0> extends ArrayList<U> {
    void callCheck(??? m) {
        m.check(this);
    }
}
```

What should be the type of the parameter m?

Also note that there can be other descendants of M with, say, C = MyList1 or some other extension of List, and still callCheck should work with those descendants as well (as long as the code

```
SomeM someM = new SomeM();
someM.check(this);
```

works, where SomeM extends M<...>)

Comment: This code compiles using java 1.8.0_77 and setting the parmaeter type to M

Comment: Yes, but then there are two warnings: raw type and type safety... Is it possible to do without it? Otherwise, there is not much point in using generics anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I got rid of the first type parameter of `M`, which is useless. The `U` there is unused in the body of `M`, and only appears once inside the definition of another bound as `? extends U`, but since `U extends U0` that's just equivalent to `? extends U0`. (If this is not your real code and `U` is used somewhere, it could probably be added back with some thought.)

This compiles:

```
interface U0 { }
static class U1 implements U0 {
    public int x = 1;
}
static class U2 extends U1 { }

static abstract class M<C extends List<? extends U0>> {
    C field;
    public abstract boolean check(C c);
}

static class M1 extends M<List<? extends U1>> {

    @Override
    public boolean check(List<? extends U1> c) {
        return !c.isEmpty() && c.get(0).x > 0;
    }

}

static class MyList<U extends U0> extends ArrayList<U> {
    void callCheck(M<? super MyList<U>> m) {
        m.check(this);
    }
}

static class MyList1 extends MyList<U2> {
}

//...
new MyList1().callCheck(new M1());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: After some thought, I realized that if there is another descendant of `M` that uses, e.g., `MyList2` instead of `List`, then `callCheck` won't work:

Comment: This is the code:

    static class M2 extends M<MyList2<? extends U1>> {

        @Override
        public boolean check(MyList2<? extends U1> c) {
            return !c.isEmpty() && c.get(0).x > 0;
        }

    }

Then, obviously, `new MyList1().callCheck(new M1());` won't work, but also `new M2().check(new MyList1());` won't work either, since the method `check` of `M2` might use some methods declared in `MyList1` and absent in `MyList`.

Comment: @AndreyShutovich: That's because `MyList` doesn't know about `MyList2`, so it can't check for `M`s that don't take `MyList` but take `MyList2`. For that, you could add another type parameter to `MyList` to indicate the subclass of `MyList` (e.g. `MyList2`) to check for, and `MyList2` would extend `MyList` setting this type parameter to itself. But there is no way to ensure that `this` is an instance of this type parameter, so you would need an abstract method like `getThis()` which returns the type parameter type, for you to pass to `check()`,and subclasses would have to implement this method